# AngularJS JSFiddle and http service

Tags: angularjs, ajax, jsfiddle

I'm working on an angularJS app and I can't seem to retrieve my JSON object from the url. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

var url = "https://jsfiddle.net/Afroza/j35e8v8h/r";

  $http.get(url).then( funtion(response) {
      $scope.info = response.data;
  })
});
```

Here's my html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

   <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>Data: {{info}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also, I'm using JSFiddle so all the html tags and angularjs scripts are included.

Comment: ` $http.get(url).then( funtion(response) ` correct it as `function`

Comment: In case you stumble upon errors, you should probably open the console panel in your browser and look for stack trace / exception

Answer (score 2):

You spelling of function is wrong. Its `funtion` in your code.

```
$http.get(url).then( function(response) {
      $scope.info = response.data;
  })
```

You can always check `console` `ctrl+shift+j` in chrome to check syntax and other js related errors.

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j35e8v8h/18/

Comment: I corrected that issue and am still not receiving my data response. Any other suggestions?